# Redirect base URL www.site.com to site.com

Tags: apache-2.2

Without using .htaccess how can i redirect www.site.com to site.com? I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  *.site.net
    Redirect permanent / http://site.net
</VirtualHost>
```

But nothing happened. It loaded my default site instead of site.net

What do i write and which file do i write it in and where in the file do i write it in (tell me its inside of `<VirtualHost *:80>` instead of making me guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild cards like `*` and `?` are only allowed with `ServerAlias` but not with `ServerName`.

Try the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.net
    ServerAlias *.site.net
    Redirect permanent / http://site.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  site.net
    # [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But you'll need to have mod_rewrite enabled in your module list. You can find out quickly by running the following:

```
# httpd -M 2>&1 | grep rewrite
 rewrite_module (shared)
```

Hope this helps.